# Control angle of arrow in matplotlib.pyplot.annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib

it is driving me nuts that the annotate arrow in the screenshot below is not straight. What am I missing? I'm suspecting it has to do with the way I specify the xy and xytext position, yet they both have the same y.

[image: arrow example]

This is how I'm specifying the annotate:

```
plt.annotate('Head Motion Cutoff',
             xy=[data.shape[0], motion_cutoff],
             xytext=[data.shape[0]+12, motion_cutoff],
             fontsize=14,
             arrowprops=dict(fc='#A9A9A9',
                             ec='#A9A9A9',
                             arrowstyle='simple',
                             shrinkA=4,
                             shrinkB=4))
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that allows to reproduce the issue? See [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the arrow is by default connected to the center of the text.

You may however change the position to which the arrow connects using the `relpos` argument of the arrowproperties.

```
plt.annotate(...,  arrowprops=dict(..., relpos=(0, 0)) )
```

The relative position is specified in coordinates of the text's bounding box.

[image]

For bottom aligned text, one would choose `relpos=(0,0)`.
For center aligned text, one would choose `relpos=(0,0.5)`.
For top aligned text, one would choose `relpos=(0,1)`.
A problem is, if the text does not contain any character (like the `"g"` here), which goes down to the bottom, then a `relpos=(0,0.2)` might make sense.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, dpi=200)
ax.grid(color='k', alpha=0.5, ls=':')

plt.annotate('Head Motion Cutoff',
         xy=[0.1, 0.8],
         xytext=[60, 0], 
         verticalalignment = "baseline",
         arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='simple',
                         fc='#A9A9A9', ec='#A9A9A9',
                         shrinkA=4, shrinkB=4,
                         relpos=(0, 0.2)),             
         fontsize=11, 
         textcoords="offset points")



ap = dict(fc='#A9A9A9', ec='#A9A9A9', arrowstyle='simple',
          shrinkA=4, shrinkB=4)

fontsize = 11
aligns = ["bottom", "top", "center"]
positions =  [dict(relpos=(0, 0.)),dict(relpos=(0, 1)),dict(relpos=(0, 0.5))]
kw = dict(fontsize=fontsize, textcoords="offset points")


for i, (align,pos) in enumerate(zip(aligns,positions)):
    ap.update(pos)
    kw.update(dict(arrowprops=ap)) 
    plt.annotate('Head Motion Cutoff (va={})'.format(align),
             xy=[0.1, i*0.2+0.2],
             xytext=[60, 0],
             va=align, ha="left", **kw)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks! Accepted this as the answer for showing the combined effects of 'relpos' and 'va'. Thanks again, my OCD is now slightly alleviated :)

Comment: why do you have `horizontalalignment = "bottom",` in the first annotate? I presume that's a typo?

Comment: OK, but that's not actually doing anything. Try changing that to `top` and you'll see it makes no difference. [`horizontalalignment`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_horizontalalignment) can take `[ 'center' | 'right' | 'left' ]` as its value, not `'bottom'`. Are you sure you didn't mean `verticalalignment` there?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Sorry for that. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's due to the vertical alignment of the text (in this case 'Head Motion Cutoff'). The arrow is aligned to the center of the text, but by default, the baseline of the text will be set to the coordinates you give in `xytext`.

The simplest fix to this is to set the [`verticalalignment` (or `va`)](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_verticalalignment) of the text to `'center'`, so everything lines up nicely.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.grid(color='k', alpha=0.5, ls=':')

plt.annotate('Head Motion Cutoff (va=bottom)',
             xy=[0.1, 0.2],
             xytext=[0.4, 0.2],
             fontsize=14,
             arrowprops=dict(fc='#A9A9A9',
                             ec='#A9A9A9',
                             arrowstyle='simple',
                             shrinkA=4,
                             shrinkB=4),
             va='bottom')

plt.annotate('Head Motion Cutoff (va=baseline)',
             xy=[0.1, 0.4],
             xytext=[0.4, 0.4],
             fontsize=14,
             arrowprops=dict(fc='#A9A9A9',
                             ec='#A9A9A9',
                             arrowstyle='simple',
                             shrinkA=4,
                             shrinkB=4),
             va='baseline')

plt.annotate('Head Motion Cutoff (va=top)',
             xy=[0.1, 0.6],
             xytext=[0.4, 0.6],
             fontsize=14,
             arrowprops=dict(fc='#A9A9A9',
                             ec='#A9A9A9',
                             arrowstyle='simple',
                             shrinkA=4,
                             shrinkB=4),
             va='top')

plt.annotate('Head Motion Cutoff (va=center)',
             xy=[0.1, 0.8],
             xytext=[0.4, 0.8],
             fontsize=14,
             arrowprops=dict(fc='#A9A9A9',
                             ec='#A9A9A9',
                             arrowstyle='simple',
                             shrinkA=4,
                             shrinkB=4),
             va='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: excellent, thanks for pointing me to the 'va' option. Very useful! I would like to have accepted your answer too, but I can only accept one :(. Accepted the other one for bringing 'relpos' in the mix too and showing that I could have chosen another number than 0, 0.5 or 1 (go figure :D)